# Is there a way to make a =CONCATENATEIFS() in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, concatenation

I have a table like below :

| Person | Bank | Credit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Julius | HSBC | 1000 |
| Julius | BoA | 200 |
| Marcus | HSBC | 500 |
| Marcus | BoC | 400 |
| Kylie | BoA | 800 |

I want to convert it to a table like that :

| Person | Banks | Credit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Julius | HSBC, BoA | 1200 |
| Marcus | HSBC, BoC | 900 |
| Kylie | BoA | 800 |

For the Column Credit, I use a formula like `=SUMIFS(C:C;A:A;A2)`

But can I have a way to make it for the column Banks? something that would be a sort of `=CONCATENATEIFS(B:B;A:A;A2)`

Bonus question : is there a way to add a separator like the `,`  in my example?

Comment: Here is a TEXTJOINIFS() UDF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858571/merge-values-of-column-b-based-on-common-values-on-column-a

Comment: If you don't have the TEXTJOIN function, you could either use a UDF in its place, as suggested by @ScottCraner, or you could use Power Query, which can aggregate your columns as you show in your desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest that you use `TEXTJOIN`.

Assuming your table is on columns A to C, and the lookup values from columns E to G, use the formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$6=$E10,$B$2:$B$6,""))
```

DRag the formula down to the other cells.

[image: Result of concatenating using TEXTJOIN an IF functions]

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function contxt(ParamArray args() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim tmptext As Variant, i As Variant, Cellv As Variant
    Dim Cell As Range
    tmptext = ""
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(args)
        If Not IsMissing(args(i)) Then
            Select Case TypeName(args(i))
                Case "Range"
                    For Each Cell In args(i)
                        tmptext = tmptext & Cell
                    Next Cell
                Case "Variant()"
                    For Each Cellv In args(i)
                        tmptext = tmptext & Cellv
                    Next Cellv
                Case Else
                    tmptext = tmptext & args(i)
            End Select
        End If
    Next i
  tmptext = Mid(tmptext, 1, Len(tmptext) - 1)
    contxt = tmptext
    
End Function
```

Create the Custom function and enter the formulas:

```
=CONTXT((IF($A$2:$A$6=F2,$B$2:$B$6&",","")))
```

[image]

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$6,F2,$C$2:$C$6)
```

[image]